# MySQL; How to GROUP BY an select newest?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following table in MySQL.

[image]

I have the following query: `SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY names`.

This will make a list where every name will only appear once but it doesn't take care of the year. I need to SELECT always the latest entry. Means e.g. `Peter | 2016` for `Peter`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try using order by too.

Comment: This will only order the result after selected. Any other idea?

Comment: ur question ia marked as duplicate. you can check the same question asked before and get ideas. if don't get let me know.

Comment: @Jyotimishra Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM  `user` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY names
ORDER BY year DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: @Jyotimishra Doesn't work, still the same.

Comment: I finally found the solution: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY year DESC) x GROUP BY names;`